# How to make state/provinces list dynamic on user profiles/registrations? with international addresses?

Tags: entities, location, google-maps

I have a site with international users, and I'm using location, user locations, and Google geocoding to show their locations on a map.

I'm using the US as the default for addresses, as most of my users are US based. The issue that I have is that the state/provinces drop down doesn't update the list for a different country until after the form is saved. The effect of this is that the newly registered users has to go back into their account an update their address if it isn't in the US.

Is there anyway to make the state/provinces list dynamic? that is to have the list match the country selected while the user is registering?

One solution to this is to email the user and remind them to update their address, but this seems like back UI and laziness.

Is there some way to refresh just the location fields before the form is submitted if it cannot be dynamic?

So, I'm not sure how to approach this and any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there's a patch for this. The last patch used against the 3.x dev module provided the desired results. [Dynamic States list patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1997658)